# .NET 7 Maui Publish Android Error IL1023 and NETSDK1144

Tags: android, maui, .net-7.0

I'm publish android found error below

Error IL1023 The path to the assembly 'MarkStep:Microsoft.Android.Sdk.ILLink.SetupStep,C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.68\targets..\tools\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.ILLink.dll' specified for '--custom-step' must be fully qualified. Project ProjectPath\ILLink 1

Error NETSDK1144 Optimizing assemblies for size failed. Optimization can be disabled by setting the PublishTrimmed property to false. Project C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.304\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.ILLink.Tasks\build\Microsoft.NET.ILLink.targets 86

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxPZh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error NETSDK1144 Optimizing assemblies for size failed. Optimization can be disabled by setting the PublishTrimmed property to false...

For this error, you can try to do the following steps:

Right click the project and select "**Properties**"

Find "**AOT**" and uncheck it:[image]

Find "**Enable trimming**" and also uncheck it:[image]